# Use an append attribute in a eloquent condition

Tags: laravel, eloquent

this is my situation of my laravel project:

- I have 3 models: Travel, Activity and Expense.
- One Travel has many Activities and many Expenses.
- Model attributes:

  - Travel: id, title, desc, date, location
  - Activity: id, travel_id, title, desc, date, prize
  - Expense: id, travel_id, title, desc, prize
- The Travel model has an append attribute called 'total_prize', that is the sum of all Expenses and Activities that it has.

So far so good. My problem is when I try to apply the filter 'available_amount <= total_prize' to Travel's list.

How can I use the append attribute 'total_prize' for get all travels less than the amount_available?

- amount_available is a post request variable.

This is the accessor for total_prize attribute:

```
 public function getTotalPrizeAttribute()
    {
        return (float) $this->activities->sum('prize') + $this->expenses->sum('prize');
    }
```

I want to do something like this:

```
Travel::where('total_prize', '<=', 'amount_available')->get();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two choices:

- Get *all* travels and then filter them (not very efficient):

```php
$travels = Travel::with('activities', 'expenses')->get()
    ->where('total_prize', '<=', $amount_available);
```

- Recreate `getTotalPrizeAttribute()` in the query:

```php
$travels = Travel::withCount([
        'activities' => function($query) {
            $query->select(DB::raw('sum(prize)'));
        },
        'expenses' => function($query) {
            $query->select(DB::raw('sum(prize)'));
        }
    ])
    ->having(DB::raw('activities_count + expenses_count'), '<=', $amount_available)
    ->get();
```

Comment: Edited one thing, amount_available is a post request variable.